# why property does not exist on type in object destructuring?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why I got error in typescript when I use Object destructuring?

The Javscript is running well. but typescript got error.

`fn` error:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type '(() => void) | { bar: () => void; }' are callable.
    Type '{ bar: () => void; }' has no call signatures.
```

`bar` error:

```
Property 'bar' does not exist on type '(() => void) | { bar: () => void; }'
```

[The code in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-mkjtax)

[image]

```
const foo = () => {
  const fn = () => { console.log('in fn'); };

  return [{ bar: () => { console.log('in bar'); } }, fn];
};

const baz = () => {
  const [{ bar }, fn] = foo();

  fn();
};

baz();
```

Comment: The second bar has no value. Each object is a key and value pair. You provided just a key. Also you're assigning a function to an array, not to a key or index of the array.

Comment: No, I return array and not object. like this: `const [ f1, f2 ] = ['xx', 'yy']`, it doesn't matter if it string or function.

Comment: Something like: `const foo = (): [{ bar: Function }, Function] => { ...` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the what the function returns and it won't complain

```js
interface Abc {
  bar: Function
}

const foo = () : [Abc, Function] => {
  const fn = () => { console.log('in fn'); };

  return [{ bar: () => { console.log('in bar'); } }, fn];
};

const baz = () => {
  const [{ bar }, fn] = foo();
  fn();
};

baz();
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-oc3thd

Comment: but why? why typescript doesn't calculate correctly the return objects?

Comment: @Jon Sud typescript is not dynamically typed therefore you need to declare the types explicitly to use the advantages provided by typescript. When you declare the return type it makes sure what you are returning is same as what has been declared as return type.

Answer (score 1):

That's because inferred type is array with items that can be or objects or functions

```
(() => void) | { bar: () => void; }
```

You can instruct typescript to resolve it as readonly tuple using `as const` [assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
return [{ bar: () => { console.log('in bar'); } }, fn] as const;
```

Now it is able to differentiate the array items' types according to position/index. And you don't have to specify the return type explicitly.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MAUBKFA%20GBvAKBhlEljjBXS2VzxPAhABsBTAOmZAHM0ByAJaUKfDAG4YAXzEEiMAE6soAV3mUA2vQBGAQ3kAuajnwNILDl16DKu%20aImSpAGnhgAujB0RT0GdNmk0DC6AF5UmMaExIGwmsF6zq4eqAggmDJyFOkE-gSh6UA)